# Workflow based on Picklist value and Field Update

Tags: apex, workflow

I want to create a Workflow and update the field based on PICKLIST Value

Picklist Field (Currency) & Value is -> A B, C, D

```
like if (Currency = 'A')

amount = Service* 10;       

else

like if (Currency = 'B')

amount = Service* 20;

else

like if (Currency = 'C')

amount = Service* 40;

else

like if (Currency = 'D')

amount = Service* 40;

else

amount = nuLL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto setup --> Create --> Workflow & Approvals --> Workflow Rules --> New Rule

Click on New Rules Select Object

Give any name for workflow rule [image] and select **created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria** and set your criteria.

Click on save. Now set up a field update. Click on add Workflow action --> New Field Update.

[image]

Now fill the name and select which field in **Field to Update** dropdown

In Formula Value (Text) = Write below code

```
 IF(ISPICKVAL(Currency , 'A'),  Service* 10,
        IF(ISPICKVAL(Currency , 'B') ,Service* 20,
            IF(ISPICKVAL(Currency , 'C') ,Service* 40, 
              IF(ISPICKVAL(Currency , 'D') ,Service* 40, 
                0
              )
            )
        )
    )
```

Write this code in Workflow field update.

---

Another answer with Case statement

```
CASE(Currency ,
       'A', Service* 10,
       'B', Service* 20,
       'C', Service* 20,
       'D', Service* 40,
       0
)
```

Comment: what need to add in the WF rule while configuring it?

Comment: you can add **created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria**

Comment: @SachinKumar check my updated ans.

Comment: `CASE` is a bit cleaner especially if the number of conditions grows over time. Fewer parens as well making it easier to edit